# Accessing model from inside Carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crop, rmagick, carrierwave

I'm trying to implement a manual crop for a web application I'm working on, and I have this so far:

```
  version :croppedversion do
    process :manualcrop => [model.crop_x, model.crop_y, model.crop_h, model.crop_w]
  end

  process :resize_to_limit => [600, 600]

  def manualcrop(x,y,h,w)
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.crop(x,y,h,w)
    end
  end
```

The problem is that model is turning up as nil.  From the documentation I've read this would be the correct way to go about it.

Any suggestions?  I've moved the call to cropping into a callback in the model for now, but would really like for it to reside inside carrierwave

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  I had

> attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

but forgot to include them the crop variables in the attr_accessible.  By doing

> attr_accessible :description, :image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

I was able to get the model crop variables.  I dont know if this would solve your issue because you're describing the model returning nil rather than the crop methods.

Comment: I ran into that issue as well, as I am horrible about keeping my attr_accessible's straight, but alas, it is the model that is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled very much with my object being nil in CarrierWave when trying to access model data.

For me, the issue was in my controller. This doesn't look like it applies too much to your situation, but I was running a query by doing: model.user.foo - It would come up nil if I was immediately assigning this user to the model after creating the object.

Comment: Where inside your carrierwave uploader where you successfully accessing model?  I can only seem to access it inside the path method and not anything custom (such as my own processors)

Comment: Unfortunately it was within the path method I fixed my own issue and no where else.

Comment: But the question is: what you did to fix the issue. show some code please.